# plotting in R with absolute values

Tags: r, plot, equation, absolute-value

I wonder if there is a straightforward way to plot the following two equations in R

x and y are variables and the rest are known parameters.

[image]

[image]

when X is a vector of dimension n then

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you want to do?  Do you want to find `(x, y)` that solves the equations, or do you want to visualize in a graph?

Comment: I need to visualize the graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a math problem rather than programming.  A bit of calculation would help the programming task a lot easier.

First, assume `c_1` and `c_2` equal zero for simplicity. We can easily recover the original scale by shifting axes. 
Then, the matrix calculation can be written as follows.

[image]

Now let `z = ax + by` and `w = cx + dy`.  Then, the first equation with absolute value metric would be written as:

[image]

From this equation, assuming that gamma is positive, you can visualize `z` and `w` as below.

[image]

So, you can find a set of (`z, w`) combinations that satisfy the requirement and convert back to `(x, y)`.

The second equation with the maximum metric can be written as follows:

[image]

This implies that `(z, w)` can be visualized as below.

[image]

Again, you can generate such `(z, w)` pairs and convert back to `(x, y)`.

Here is an R code for the first equation.  You can try the second on your own.

```
library(ggplot2)

# A is (a,b; c,d) matrix
A <- matrix(c(1, 2, -1, 0), 
            nrow=2, ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)
gamma <- 1
c1 <- 0.2
c2 <- 0.1

###############################
z <- seq(-gamma, gamma, length=100)
w <- abs(gamma - abs(z))

z <- c(z, z)
w <- c(w, -w)

qplot(z, w) + coord_fixed()

# computing back (x,y) from (z,w)
z_mat <- rbind(z, w)
x_mat <- solve(A, z_mat)
x <- x_mat[1,] + c1
y <- x_mat[2,] + c2

qplot(x, y) + coord_fixed()
################################
```